# Is it normal that the daemon log in the GUI shows 290 days AHEAD?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, logs

Is it normal that the daemon log shows 290 days ahead? 
[image: gui daemon log]

Comment: Yes, it is normal. See [here](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/407/meaning-of-62-days-ahead-message-after-full-node-has-finished-synchronizing) for more deails.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. That is normal. Some of the nodes you connect to will be running old versions of Monero with outdated blokchains. Your daemon should eventually block some of these automatically. As long as it can reach a peer with a current copy of the blockchain, then there are no problems.

See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/407/meaning-of-62-days-ahead-message-after-full-node-has-finished-synchronizing) for more details.